# d3js: Path animation wrapping around screen

Tags: animation, d3.js

I'm using the standard point-along-path transition functionality as described [here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1705868).  What I am trying to do is to start the animation in the middle of the screen, then go to the leftmost end of the screen, and then wrap around such that the path continues from the rightmost end of the screen back towards the middle.  I attempted to do this by simply setting consecutive points in the path from the leftmost point to the rightmost point. In that scenario, when the object reaches the leftmost end, it moves across the screen from the leftmost end to the rightmost end before continuing to the middle.  Is there a way to make it wrap around such that when it reaches the leftmost end, it immediately continues from the rightmost end?  I have been able to achieve this by using 2 distinct paths, but want to be able to do it in one path.